# Error when running code using pickle load

Tags: python, tensorflow, pickle

I'm doing my code exactly the same with  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y1ZrOs9s2QA&t=4124s in minute 1:11:09.
I write this code :

pickle_in = open("venv/model_trained.p","rb")

model = pickle.load(pickle_in)

It showed an error like this when I tried to run it.
[Error that I got after running the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9GRN.png)

Is someone having the same issue as me?

Thank you.

Best Regards,

Bhetrand

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I solved it, the problem is on the python version that doesn't support TensorFlow version 2.0.0, I guess pickle can work well in TensorFlow 2.0.0 and we need the python version 3.5- 3.7 to run tensor flow 2.0.0.